# Постраничная навигация в таблице

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Помогите сделать постраничную навигацию по выводу таблиц, к примеру по 20 строк на странице, вот код

```html
<table>
    <thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Дата</th>        
        <th>Время</th> 
        <th>Город</th>
  <th>Страна</th>
  <th>IP</th>  
  <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Фамилия</th>
  <th>Телефон</th>
  <th>Емайл</th>  
    </tr>
    </thead>
<?php 

    $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
  or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect_to_db)
  or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());


    $qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `usertable` ORDER BY `dt`")
  or die(mysql_error());
 
   
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $data['dt'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $data['tm'] . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $data['city'] . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $data['country'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $data['ip'] . '</td>';  
  echo '<td>' . $data['name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $data['lname'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $data['phone'] . '</td>'; 
  echo '<td>' . $data['email'] . '</td>';  
  echo '</tr>';
 }
 
    echo '</tbody>';
 echo '</table>';

    // закрываем соединение с сервером  базы данных
    mysql_close($connect_to_db);
?>
```

Comment: переставайте использовать mysql. переходите на mysqli.

Comment: почему вам не нрав mysql?

Comment: На сервере PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Замените while на for, выводите в цикле 20 записей, после генерируйте ссылку и с ней передавайте значение последней итерации цикла. На этой же странице  проверяйте get и на основании проверки перестраивайте таблицу, начиная перебор массива с индекса равного значению последней итерации(который передаёте). Один из вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение LIMIT может использоваться для ограничения количества строк, возвращенных командой SELECT.

LIMIT принимает один или два числовых аргумента. Эти аргументы должны быть целочисленными константами. Если заданы два аргумента, то первый указывает на начало первой возвращаемой строки, а второй задает максимальное количество возвращаемых строк. 
Начальное смещение равно 0 , т.е :

```
`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5,10;` # возвращает строки 6-15
```

Если задан один аргумент, то он показывает максимальное количество возвращаемых строк:

```
`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5;` # возвращает первых 5 строк
```

Другими словами, LIMIT n эквивалентно LIMIT 0,n.

Создайте переменную $page=1 и $rows_on_page=20

```
$offset = ($page-1)*rows_on_page;

"SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset,$rows_on_page";
```